# Como remover vogais de uma String JS?

Tags: javascript

Quero criar uma função em JS que remove as vogais de uma palavra.
Tentei com replace, expressão regular, mas não consegui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar esta regex que irá remover inclusive vogais acentuadas:

```
/[aeiouà-ú]/gi

Flags:
g -> global. Busca por todas as ocorrências.
i -> case insensitive. Não faz distinção entre maiúsculas e minúsculas.
```

**Veja:**

```js
function removeVogaisString( remove ){
   return remove.replace(/[aeiouà-ú]/gi,'');
}

var resultado = removeVogaisString( "OláÁéôãõ, mundo!" );

console.log( resultado );
```

Comment: Qual a finalidade do */gi* existente no replace?

Comment: `g` (global): irá procurar todas as ocorrências. `i` (case insensitive): não faz distinção de maiúsculas e minúsculas.

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo funcional com expressões regular:

```js
const example = 'Olá, mundo!';

console.log(example.replace(/(a|e|i|o|u)/gi, ''));
```

#### Adicionando mais caracteres

Caso você quiser adicionar mais caracteres para serem removidos, basta adicionar mais ao lado de `|u`.
Por exemplo, se você quiser remover a letra `z` também, basta alterar a expressão de:

```
/(a|e|i|o|u)/gi
```

Para:

```
/(a|e|i|o|u|z)/gi
```

Comment: Mais simples é `/[aeiou]/`

Comment: Eu havia tentado algo mais ou menos assim, mas retornou **undefined**.   
function removeVogaisString( remove ){ <br/> remove.replace(/[[^aAeEiIoOuU]]/g,''); } var resultado = removeVogaisString( "Hoje vai chover." ); console.log( resultado );